# How can I compare 2 arrays creating a new array with the changes?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, readprocessmemory

I am reading the CHAT from an application with readprocessmemory which I want to monitor for events.

```
    Attach() 'attach to process
    Dim chatStart As Integer = &H6E3220

    Dim lines As Integer = 150 'chatlines
    Dim offset As Integer = 98 'offset between chat lines
    Dim arrAddressList(0 To lines) As IntPtr
    Dim addressToAdd As IntPtr = chatStart 'first line
    arrAddressList(0) = addressToAdd 'assign firstline

    For i = 1 To lines 'loop the other 149 lines and assign the address
        chatStart += offset 'skip to the address of the next line
        arrAddressList(i) = chatStart  'assign the new address to its place in the array
    Next
    For j = 0 To arrAddressList.Count - 1
        Dim chatText As String = MEMMGR.ReadAsciiString(arrAddressList(j), 104)
        If chatText = "" Then 'chat lines not filled, exit
            Exit For
        Else
            AddLog(chatText) 'puts into text box
        End If
    Next
```

If the application has just started, and all the lines are not filled, then there is no need to cycle all 150 lines.

The chat box is max 150 lines, when it reaches the 150, all the chat is pushed up so the 150th line is now the latest line of chat text.

My current code will read all the chat in the chat box.

The only way I can think of to detect a change is to read it ALL twice, and then compare the results and loop until it finds lines in the arrays which are different - these would be the lines which are 'updated'. There could be more than one line that is updated depending on how active the chat is so would need to have another array containing ALL the line changes from the last chat retrieval.

However I've no idea where to start when I come to do it as it seems very confusing, Could someone with a bit more logic in this matter point me in the right direction, or explain the best (fastest) way to do this?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read this, I hope it wasn't too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you chat lines are unique, you could use LINQ:

```
Dim chat1() As String = {"abc", "bcd", "cde"}
Dim chat2() As String = {"abc", "bcd", "cde", "def"}

Dim diff() As String = chat2.Except(chat1).ToArray
```

Ideally you don't need to read all lines, just go from bottom to top.

Stop when found a record you already have in your dictionary.

Comment: Hi, the new chat line could possibly be the same as the last but the Except function looks very useful, I shall take a look - thanks for your input!

Comment: @Nookster: You need to find a way to distinguish lines old vs new. If you have a message ID, you could use that. `Except` works just fine for numeric types. Alternatively, a tuple of timestamp/user_id/message_length may be enough to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: There lies my problem :) there is no timestamp! I can't create one either as then it will depend when I read the memory (which is not when the chat message was sent) All I have is "[name] message" or just simply "message"

Comment: @Nookster: But you are reading from memory! There must be some kind of ID bound to every message. Perhaps even an object with many useful properties. It may not be easy to find, but internally it cannot work without it. The server needs to know how to validate message uniqueness.

Comment: I am reading directly from the chat box it applies the text to, only thing there is the text!

Comment: @Nookster: Then your problem has no general solution. Consider the following situation. Read 1: 150 lines containing `A` as a text. Read 2: 150 lines containing `A` as a text. Did anything change between your reads? Well, it does not appear so. However, if the chat discussion went on fast, it could have been some conversation in between. You never know without unique ID of the message.

Comment: Read1 only contains 150 lines on the first read if all the chat lines are full. Read1 if already full will return only the read from the last memory address(line150), the only way I can think is to have a loop or timer reading the very last line quickly (it's not a lot of data, max 128 length) and if it changes, then this is the line that is different. If the same message is sent twice saying the same thing it can be ignored anyway. I know it is very scrappy or if it will even work, I can't think of another way.

Comment: If the chat lines are not filled it will have to read the address which returns nothing(no text there) until it HAS text there. gah. All very confusing.

Comment: @Nookster: Yes, this approach is not stable, meaning there is a number of obvious test cases where it would always fail. In this case I suggest you find another approach. Dealing with heuristics requires a long term maintenance effort. Another thought - why do you need to read those chat lines? Are you looking for anything specific? What's the chat application you are using? It may have an API, which you could use instead.

Comment: In my previous message, "message" should have been server message. It is either a message from the server or a chat message. It reads chat from a game, the game gives attack output into chat, I wish to read these messages and calculate average damage etc. for statistics however, the same message could be a chat message from a user, or a server message.